# How to display menu icons for the menu categories in the Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I can easily show icons in the menu for the subitems but what if I wanted to shows icon for the category menu items? 
I tried like the code example below but it simply ignores android:icon parameter and displays just text.
First screenshot is what I get and the next one how I would like to get it looking.

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">


<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_lists"
    android:title="@string/lists">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_lists"
            android:title="@string/my_lists" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_list_search"
            android:title="@string/search_and_apply" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_list_applications"
            android:title="@string/applications" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_list_banned"
            android:title="@string/banned" />
    </menu>
</item>


<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback"
    android:title="@string/feedback">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_feedback_from_others"
            android:title="@string/from_others" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_feedback_to_leave"
            android:title="@string/i_need_to_leave" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_feedback"
            android:title="@string/i_have_left" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_feedback_info"
            android:title="@string/banned" />
    </menu>
</item>


<item android:title="@string/logout" />
```

Question is, if there is menu icon property why it doesn't get displayed for top category menu items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Below Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_lists"
        android:title="@string/lists">

       <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_lists"
                android:title="@string/my_lists"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_list_search"
                android:title="@string/search_and_apply" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_list_applications"
                android:title="@string/applications" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_list_banned"
                android:title="@string/banned" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_feedback"
        android:title="@string/feedback"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_feedback_from_others"
                android:title="@string/from_others" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_feedback_to_leave"
                android:title="@string/i_need_to_leave" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_my_feedback"
                android:title="@string/i_have_left" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_feedback_info"
                android:title="@string/banned" />
    </group>
```